# Prove that $|Re(z)|, |Im(z)| \leq |z|$ for complex variable $z$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that $|Re(z)|, |Im(z)| \leq |z|$. So I set $z=a+bi$ and got $(|a|,|b|) \leq |a+bi|$. So then I got $(a,b) \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2} $, $(a+bi) \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2} $. I squared both sides and got $a^2 +2abi -b^2 \leq a^2 + b^2$. Simplyfing and canceling things out I eventually got $ai \leq b$. At this point I can see that any real times an imaginary will be smaller than any real; since this is true that means my first statement is true too.

Did I do this right? I think I had the right idea I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: We need to show, $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ge|a|\iff a^2+b^2\ge a^2\iff b^2\ge0$$ which is true

Comment: So what about the part of |Im(z)|?

Comment: So then I don't get (a,b)?

Comment: what is $(a,b)$? See also: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/complex_compare.shtml

Comment: Well its because I thought since I was asked $
Re(z)|, |Im(z)|$ that gave me |a|,|b| which gives me (a,b). Is that wrong?

Comment: please explain the meaning of your notation $(a,b)?$. I think, the question meant $|$Re$(z)|\le|z|,|$Im$(z)|\le|z|$

Comment: Oh its because I assumed that it was an ordered pair because of the comma that was there

Comment: How to compare an ordered pair with a positive real number

Comment: Your right. I guess that's why I had a difficult time understanding it. It makes more sense now that I know it is split up. Thank you.

Comment: Can someone fix the tags? I'm not sure which would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Re(z)=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}\implies|Re(z)|=|\frac{z+\bar z}{2}|\iff |Re(z)|=|\dfrac z2 + \frac{\bar z}{2}| \le \dfrac 12|z|+\dfrac 12|\bar z|$(by triangle inequality). Since $|\bar z| = |z|$, then we have $|Re(z)| \le \dfrac 12|z| + \dfrac 12|z| = |z|$. Similar for $|Im(z)|,$ with $Im(z)=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}$.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense. Neither $i\leq1$ nor $i>1$ is true.
About the original problem, do you know about Pythagoras' theorem? And about the fact, that hypotenuse is the longest in a right triangle?

Comment: Yes I don know the theorem. Yes I did have a concern when I had $i$ at the end. That's why I wanted to get other peoples opinion

Comment: In naive geometrical sense you should prove that hypotenuse is longer than catheti.